# Why is the metric in Kaluza Klein theory set up in the way that it is?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, kaluza-klein

Since the product of the electomagnetic potential with itself and the square of the radion field is added to the 4D space time metric, 
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
g_{\mu\nu}+A_\mu A_\nu\phi^2 & \phi^2A_\mu \\
\phi^2A_\nu & \phi^2 \\ \end{array} \right)$$
It would seem that $\phi$ and $A_\mu$ have a more direct effect on the geometry of 4D spacetime than just the electromagnetic field in standard GR-wouldn't this effect be observably different than what would be the standard curvature from EFE?

Comment: It makes it easier to write the inverse of the metric.

Comment: @Prahar Yeah I've seen that the inverse metric makes sense-but the line element is still very different than it is in standard GR

Comment: What do you mean? This is not standard GR anyway. You can see the purpose of writing the metric in this way, by writing down the action and actually performing the KK reduction from which it becomes immediately obvious that $g_{\mu\nu}$ becomes the metric of the un-compactified space and $A_\mu$ behaves as a propagating gauge d.o.f. If I write the metric in a different form, then the interpretation of the various components in that form will be different.

Comment: Clearly I don't know enough about the theory, do you have any good resources for learning about it?